Beamer Template Colours
I wish to have a standard colour for my beamer slides (yellow), though occasionally use a special colour (orange). The code below all works well until the final slide, as I'd like slide A2 to be yellow and not sure how I achieve this. Many thanks!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1.5ex]{secsubsec}%
    \raggedright
    \hspace*{1em}%
    {\small{EMP}\sffamily \hfill\small\color{secinhead}\insertsection\insertsubsection}%
    \hspace*{2em}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip-3pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.8ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%
  \raggedright\hspace*{1em}\Large\insertframetitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}
\setbeamercolor{secsubsec}{fg=secinhead,bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=secinhead,bg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=black!50}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=titlebg}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan}
 \definecolor{secinhead}{RGB}{252, 252, 250}


\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{222, 131, 68}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{231, 182, 13}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{special}[]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1.5ex
            % ,leftskip=0.3cm,rightskip=0.3cm
            ]{frametitle}%
               \raggedright \hspace*{1em}\small{EMP}\hfill\color{white}\raggedleft\insertsection%
                \hspace*{0.5em}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myorange}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{standard}[]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
        \leavevmode%
        \hbox{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=1.5ex
            % ,leftskip=0.3cm,rightskip=0.3cm
            ]{frametitle}%
                \raggedright \hspace*{1em}\small{EMP}\hfill\color{white}\raggedleft\insertsection%
                \hspace*{0.5em}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
    }
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=titlebg}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Standard section}
\begin{frame}
This is standard
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]{A1}
This is a plain slide
\end{frame}

\section{Special section}
\begin{frame}[special]
This is special
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]{A2}
This is another plain slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}


you need to use the standard key to reset the colours as an option to the frame - the same way you use special to set orange, use standard to set back to yellow. probably standard,plain (untested).

You could use the same technique as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1163#a1370 to automatically limit your modifications to the special frames. Here an example which changes the colour of the frametitle. You can use the same technique also for other templates, e.g. the headline.
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{222, 131, 68}
\definecolor{titlebg}{RGB}{231, 182, 13}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=titlebg}%

\makeatletter
\providebool{specialframe}
\define@key{beamerframe}{special}[true]{
  \booltrue{specialframe}
  \begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=myorange}%
}

\apptocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{specialframe}{%
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{specialframe}
  }{}
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[special]
\frametitle{Special}
This is special
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Normal}
This is another plain slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}


